# nginx, two websites on two ports to two URLs instead?

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have experience with IIS but not with nginx (on Windows).
I have two websites on a server as follows;

`http://servername:port1000`

`http://servername:port2000`

and would like the following:

`http://site1.ourdomain.com`

`http://site2.ourdomain.com`

I'm wondering how to solve it. DNS can't be used and I guess Azure application proxy cant be used either?
Some setting within the web application configuration I guess.

Any assistance appreciated, links etc.

Comment: You need a reverse proxy such as Nginx or Apache accepting requests on the domain, fulfilling the request from whichever server on whichever port.

Comment: If you take a look at the various examples, such as https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/ You can see `proxy_pass` can be used to easily implement rewrite rules for your cases.